# Load an element value of an array to another array Xcode Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays

Here I am getting the `cityName1` with the city names like Piscataway, Iselin, Broklyn etc fetched from the `tgpList1` array and I need to put the values into an array called `item5`.

There are 133 records fetched by the above iteration. The following code stores only the last record's `cityName1` and not the entire list of city names though inside the loop.

I tried many ways but I am missing something.

`tgpList1` is an array.
`tgpDAO` is an NSObject with two objects `NSString *airportCode` and `NSString *cityName`

```
NSArray *item5 = [[NSArray alloc]init]; 
for (int currentIndex=0; currentIndex<[tgpList1 count]; currentIndex++)
{
    tgpDAO *tgpTable = (tgpDAO *)[self.tgpList1 objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
    NSLog(@"The array values are %@",tgpList1);

    NSString *cityName1 = tgpTable.cityName;

    item5 =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:cityName1, nil];
}
```

Comment: Formatting your question well will encourage better, faster answers. I have edited your question this time, but please consider formatting questions similar to this next time.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the notes, will follow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mutable array.

```
{

   NSMutableArray *item5 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:nil];
   for (int currentIndex=0; currentIndex<[tgpList1 count]; currentIndex++) {            

       tgpDAO *tgpTable = (tgpDAO *)[self.tgpList1 objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
       NSLog(@"The array values are %@",tgpList1);
       NSString *cityName1 = tgpTable.cityName;
       [item5 addObject:cityName1];

   }
}
```

Comment: Hey Neo, great just one little change of NSArray to NSMutableArray did the trick. Thanks a lot. Thanks for all support from stackoverflow. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
item5 =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:cityName1, nil];
```

use

```
[item5 addObject:cityName1];
```

There are more ways of achieving that. However, this is the one that is designed for that purpose and the most "readable" from my pont of view.

If you need to clear the contents of item5 before then call

```
[item5 removeAllObjects];
```

right before the for loop.

What you were doing: arrayWithObjects allways creates a new array that ist made of the objects that are passed to it as aguments. If you do not use ARC, then you would create some serious memory leak with your code because arrayWithObjects creates and retains an object on every loop and on the next loop all references to the array object, that was just created, are lost without being released. If you do ARC then you do not have to worry about in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *myCities = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2]; // will grow if needed.

for( some loop conditions )
{
  NSString* someCity = getCity();
  [myCities addObject:someCity];
}

NSLog(@"number of cities in array: %@",[myCities count]);
```